# supertest TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

i'm trying to integrate test an express app, but it keeps giving me error. here is the code for my test: (note: i only included the necessary part, because its multiple files and it won't be usefull anyway)

```
const request = require('supertest')

let server;

beforeEach(()=>{ server = require('../../../src/index') });
afterEach(()=>{ server.close() });

describe('POST', ()=>{
    it('should check if user sent required parameters', async ()=>{
        const res = await request(server).post('/users')
        expect(res.status).toBe(400)
    })
})
```

and here is what i get in console:

```
● POST › should check if user sent required parameters

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')

      4 |
      5 | beforeEach(()=>{ server = require('../../../src/index') });
    > 6 | afterEach(()=>{ server.close() });
        |                        ^
      7 |
      8 | describe('POST', ()=>{
      9 |     it('should check if user sent required parameters', async ()=>{

      at Object.close (test/integration/routes/users.test.js:6:24)
```

here is my problem:
I CAN access the `close()` method in `beforeEach()`, but i CAN NOT access it in `afterEach()`. in fact, i can't access it anywhere besides the `befoeEach()` function. i have already exported the necessary requirements in `index.js`.

Comment: Why not simply use `const server = require(...)`? What's the point of requiring the `index` module for every test?

Comment: there is no point actually XD. but i tried using a single `server` and it still doesn't work. i will not recognize `close()` as a method on the object.

Comment: This entirely depends on what `../../../src/index` exports

Comment: Show the code of the `../../../src/index`

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute a one-time setup. closing and re-opening the connection after every test might be the cause of the issue:

```
const { setgroups } = require('process')
const request = require('supertest');

let server;

beforeAll(() => {
  server = require('../../../src/index');
});

afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});
```